# Разница между .h и .hpp

Tags: c++

В чем разница между файлами с расширениями `.h` и `.hpp` в *C++*? Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Строго говоря разницы между ними нет совсем. Разница может быть лишь в том, как IDE их интерпретирует. `.h`, если следовать некоторой логике, это заголовок для C(`.c`), тогда как `.hpp` это заголовок для C++(`.cpp`, `.cxx` etc.). Но всё это условности и зависят от предпочтений и используемых IDE. К примеру, в Visual Studio мы имеем `.h` и `.cpp` файлы, по умлочанию.

Единственно, на мой взгляд, где различное именование может принести пользу, это в проекте, где сочетается C и C++ код. Тогда стоит иметь `.h`/`.c` для C-кода и `.hpp`/`.cpp` для C++ когда. Других применений, кроме персональных предочтений, я не вижу.

Comment: А почему тогда при попытке указать в файле `.hpp`, что должен делать метод класса, например так: `void test::test(){ ... }`, g++ не видел этого в упор?

Comment: @egordorichev, `hpp` это загловок, Вы, видимо, пытаетесь использовать его как файл с кодом.

Comment: но в `.h`, такой трюк катит, хотя это не совсем хорошо.

Comment: ну вообще это не трюк, это нормальная ситуация. Просто я решил, что у вас есть `.h` файл с интерфейсом, который вы реализуете в `.hpp` файле. Мне сложно судить о gcc, т.к. я им не пользуюсь и не знаю, что ему не нравится.

Answer (score 14):

Принципиальной разницы в поведении препроцессора в зависимости от расширения хедера нет. По большей части *ему плевать на расширение*, он включит файл с любым расширением или без него.

Разные расширения для С-ных и С++-ных хедеров сделаны скорее для удобства программистов. Если видите хедер .hpp - даже не пытайтесь включать его в проект, написанный на чистом С, потому что, скорее всего, в нём будут описаны структуры, характерные только для C++ (классы, шаблоны и т. п.). Хедер .h можно (с оглядкой на то, что C [не является](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples) подмножеством C++) включать в проекты, написанные на C++. Также IDE может применять различные правила форматирования и подсветки синтаксиса для хедеров .h и .hpp.